# Symfony create Java object

Tags: java, php, symfony, zend-framework

I currently have an old Zend Framework application and want to create a new one with the Symfony Framwork.

I have calls like :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $javaObject = new Java("i.guess.i.have.an.adress.here");

    $javaObject->setRBOAccount();
    $this->_objJava = $javaObject;
}
```

I'm not the author of this script so I'm not really sure how I have to use it!
The only thing I know is that the "new Java()" is an object from Zend.

I want to create the same type of object in Symfony, but I don't know how

I have to do it.

I've heard about a JavaBridge but I don't have much info about it :/

Do you have any idea this problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/fa/book.java.php

Comment: @Gerry, I'm trying to find the source of this but it isn't on http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/java and I don't find it on http://pecl.php.net/

Comment: Apart from linking the doc, I'm afraid I can't help you. Seems this library has been abandoned though, so finding support might prove hard.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I saw :/
I also found this : http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php
The JavaBridge component but I'm not sure it's compatible with Symfony!

Comment: Apart from that they might require different PHP versions, I don't see how Symfony has anything to do with this?

Comment: In fact, I don't know either! Maybe if it creates any conflit. I'm trying to create the local Tomcat server to work with the JavaBridge. 
Do you know if the "new \java()" exists in PHP?

Comment: No not by default, you need to install the linked extension for that.

Comment: Ok, I'll come back if I have anything new and interesting! ;) Thanks for your comments!